# Matplotlib (Python) normalizing data

Tags: python, matplotlib, normalization

Well I'm trying to normalize some (infrared) thermography data, to display it later.

However I'm stuck at normalizing, I could of course do it by hand, but I wonder why the matplotlib code is not working, the python code is shown below:

```
import numpy as N
import matplotlib.colors as colors

test2 = N.array([100, 10, 95])
norm = colors.Normalize(0,100)
for pix in N.nditer(test2, op_flags=['readwrite']):
    val = (norm.process_value(pix)[0])
    print (val)

img = norm.process_value(test2)[0]
print(img)
```

Now I expect vals OR img to show the correct processed data. Depending on what `matplotlib.colors.Normalize.process_value` actually should get as argument.

But in any case: both functions do not normalize and just return the original function.. Not on the `[0, 1]` interval at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation of Normalize](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.Normalize) might be a bit deceiving here: `process_value` is a function which is only used for preprocessing (and *static*). The actual usage is described with this sentence:

> A class which, when called, can normalize data into the [0.0, 1.0]
>   interval.

Thus the normalization happens when you *call* the class:

```
import numpy as N
import matplotlib.colors as colors

test2 = N.array([100, 10, 95])
norm = colors.Normalize(0,100)
for pix in N.nditer(test2, op_flags=['readwrite']):
    val = (norm(pix))
    print (val)

img = norm(test2)
print(img)
```

Output:

```
1.0
0.1
0.95
[ 1.    0.1   0.95]
```

Comment: why do you put the call in parenthese?

Comment: I tried to change as little as possible from the code of the question. The brackets were there so I left them